# Proof that 2 and 3 are the only siamese twins that exist!

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Let us say that two prime number p and q are siamese twins if *|p-q|=1*. List all the siamese twins that exist, and prove your list is complete.**

**Proof**: 2 and 3 are prime numbers and 3-2=1. Therefore 2 and 3 are siamese twins. Lets assume that there exists another even prime number k and *k* $\neq$ 2. Since *k* is even we say that *k* = *2t* for some integer *t*. Thus *k* is divisble by 2, by itself, and the number 1. This is a contradiction, therefore *k* cannot be a prime number. Thus 2 is the only even prime number which means every other prime number is odd. The shortest distance between any two odd numbers is 2. Therefore 2 and 3 are the only existing siamese twins.

"Should I also prove that the shortest distance between any two odd numbers is 2? or should i just mention it?"

"Is my proof good enough?"

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Mod 6 will do fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the proof is OK, but can be improved. It is not hard to prove that the distance between two odd numbers is always $2$ or more, but still, another sentence about it would not hurt, would it?

Comment: No it won't. :) Thanks. Will try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I also prove that the shortest distance between any two odd numbers is 2? or should i just mention it?

Eh, I would just mention it.

> Is my proof good enough?

Mostly, but the proof would be easier to follow if you break it up into paragraphs and explicitly announce the goal of each step. Additions in bold:

> $2$ and $3$ are prime numbers and $3-2=1$. Therefore $2$ and $3$ are siamese twins.
>
> **Now, let's prove that the list is complete. First, I claim that $2$ is the only even prime number. Assume by contradiction** that there exists another even prime ... etc etc ... Thus $2$ is the only even prime number which means every other prime number is odd.
>
> **If $p,q$ are siamese twins, they cannot both be odd, because** the shortest distance between any two odd numbers is $2$. **Therefore one of $p,q$ is even, and by the preceding paragraph, one of $p,q$ equals $2$.**

Now there's a step that you glossed over: why does that force the other twin to be $3$?

> **The other twin must be $1$ or $3$. But $1$ is not prime!** Therefore 2 and 3 are the only existing siamese twins.

Maybe that's too verbose, so you'll want to find your own happy medium.